# Drupal Photos Not Aligning

Tags: html, css, drupal, alignment

I'm trying to get the 6 small photos to align in a horizontal line, but everywhere that I try to get it to inline-block in the css doesn't help. What do I do?
http://www.kiriosities.com/products/carnevale-di-venezia-mirror

[image]

Comment: What about `.field-item { display: inline-block; }`?

Comment: That didn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: It seemed to work fine when I applied it to the page.

Comment: I tried adding it to my styles.css and it didn't change anything. Did you apply it to something different?

Comment: Added it to `.field-item { display: inline-block; }` via Chrome Dev Tools. I also did `.field-items { text-align: center; }` and added some padding to `.field-item` to mimic what you have on the site now with the flex solution. Works like a charm. Depending on your browser support levels flexbox may not be a viable solution for you. Hence my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Give following css: `display:flex` will make your image in horizontal line and `justify-content: space-around;` will make space between them.

```
.field-items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

**Edit:**

If don't want to center then remove `justify-content` from `.field-items`  and use following css:

```
.field-item {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Learn more about [flexbox here.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) It will support in all latest browser.

Comment: That fixed that issue, but then also centered the rest of the objects on the page (you can see it updated on the link)

Comment: Browser support for [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). IE is the main concern.

Comment: @ketan that fixed it, but now the padding property isn't spacing them out correctly. I increase it and they don't move away from each other at all. If anything, I guess I'll just go with the centered

Comment: @LindsayJacoby Can you update that on live. So, i can check it out.

Comment: @ketan it should be up live

Comment: @LindsayJacoby I can not check updates on live. It looks same as previous.

Comment: @ketan it is showing up on mine. It just looks like they're all in a row but there's no padding between the pictures at all

Comment: @LindsayJacoby give screen shot here. And update your code here.

Comment: @ketan I edited my original posting to reflect the changes and included a screenshot

Comment: @LindsayJacoby You have added padding to `.field-items` instead of `.field-item`. Check both spelling not to `items` it's `item`. Check my answer.

Comment: `display: flex;` is in `.field-items` and `padding: 0 10px;` in `.field-item`.

Comment: @ketan I changed it and it completely messed up the formatting on my site. I'll add a screenshot above

Comment: @ketan No, I changed it back since editing the .field-item changed the formatting of elements on the entire site